# What's the best way to run some conditional if the next action is anywhere but the place you want the user to go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm currently working on a personal project but stuck while trying to figure out the best way to hook into a particular point in the request cycle.

So what I want to accomplish is: from the "new" action (inside the child object's controller), I want to delete the associated parent object if the user lands up anywhere else but the "create" action as the next action. So far I'm thinking I want to write a private method that calls destroy on the parent object as a conditional if next action is anywhere else but "create" but I can't seem to find the right callback that precisely fits my particular situation. Can anyone suggest a good solution?

Here's my code to the respective controllers.

Parent Controller:

```
class EncountersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :verify_if_logged_in, :authorize_provider, :set_patient_by_id, :view_all_patient_encounters
    
    def index
        @encounter = Encounter.new
    end

    def create
        @encounter = Encounter.new(encounter_params)
        @encounter.provider = current_user
        @encounter.patient = @patient
        if @encounter.save
            redirect_to new_patient_encounter_soap_path(@patient, encounter)
        else
            render :index
        end
    end

    private

    def set_patient_by_id
        @patient = Patient.find_by(id: params[:patient_id])
    end

    def view_all_patient_encounters
        @encounters = @patient.encounters
    end

    def encounter_params
        params.require(:encounter).permit(:encounter_type)
    end
end
```

Child Controller:

```
class SoapsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_patient_by_id, :set_encounter_by_id

    def new
        @soap = SOAP.new
    end

    def create
        #If I don't end up here immediately after the new action for whatever reason
        #I want to destroy the newly created parent object
    end

    private

    def set_patient_by_id
        @patient = Patient.find_by(id: params[:patient_id])
    end

    def set_encounter_by_id
        @encounter = Encounter.find_by(id: params[:encounter_id])
    end
end
```

Once I get to the new action of my SoapsController from the create action of my EncountersController, I want to destroy the associated Encounter object if I don't end up in Soaps#create as my next action.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I see first you are creating an Encounter from a form and then post that is submitted, you are moving to `Soap#new` to further create Soap for the mentioned encounter. Why don't you do the same in the Encounter's form? What's stopping you from doing that? Would like to know more on this to provide better answer that helps you. You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on the Encounter model, and update the form rendered during `Encounter#new` action to have Soap related attrs too, right?

Comment: Agreed ... although it probably is technically possible, you should try and avoid creating the record before you actually want to create it

Comment: @NaveenHonestRaj Hey, thanks for reaching out! Yeah I think I see what you're saying. So I had it set up this way because there are 3 types of Encounters which all get a class of its own, one of them being SOAP. So from the `Encounters#index`, I wanted to list all the Encounters the patient has along with its type. And then also a form to create a new encounter which takes them to the `#new` action on the respective types. But now that you mention it, I guess it makes more sense to take them to `Encounters#new` instead and then used `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the type they want to create.

Comment: @hiddencilantro I can understand your case. But always if there's a way to avoid creation of unnecessary(hanging) object, we should probably try to achieve things with that. Personally IMO, with having made a lot of bad decisions , leaving an hanging record/object is always a bother. I hope the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` works out fine for you. If not, please feel free to ping me on any of my handles. Good luck @hiddencilantro :))

Comment: @NaveenHonestRaj Definitely. Thanks again!